# Skeptic’s dystopian future in which everybody but him believes in the supernatural

Tags: story-identification, dystopia, powers

In the late 1990's or early 2000's, I read a short story online about a skeptic who lived in a near future in which every sort of supernatural thing was believed by everyone but himself, (quack healing, alien visitation, witchcraft, aromatherapy, cryptozoology, spoon-bending, conspiracy theories) if you can name it, they believed it.

He was frustrated at how little good it did to point out logical inconsistencies. He got arrested by the inquisitor for consorting with grey-aliens or succubi.  He had to stand trial and the judge allowed mumbo jumbo evidence.  The judge took breaks because the negative energy from the skeptic's questions distressed the judge.

I think there might have been an annoyed neighbor who falsely accused the protagonist.

I think it ends with the protagonist found guilty.

But it's clear in the world of the story that supernatural phenomenon are all fake.

The whole story was less than 20 pages.

What was the title?